# MySQL WHERE Comparing Multiple Values IN Multple Values

Tags: mysql, where-in

Is there a way to achieve this in MySQL (using pseudocode):

```
 SELECT .... WHERE (1,4,3,6) IN (SELECT id FROM atable);
```

whereby subquery "SELECT ... atable" returns row ids 3,9,8,1

The desired effect is to do something where the 2 sets of field overlap i.e. 3 and 1 in the above example.

Reason? I have a need to compare (from PHP) a field with comma separated values and perform an action where the records are applicable. However the option of doing this in PHP is not possible in my use case for some other reason too convoluted to explain here.

I've been searching on the 'net but not stumbled on anything like it.

Comment: That syntax is a "row constructor", which is not what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want

```
SELECT id FROM atable WHERE id IN (1,4,3,6);
```

If the `id` doesn't exist in `atable`, it's not going to show up in the results.  If an `id` is not among the (1,4,3,6) list, it's also not going to show up.  What you get then is the intersection.